# Can I force RavenDB to allow IDocumentSession.Store() to accept an entity with existing id?

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have an application which I am upgrading from RavenDB 1 to RavenDB 2. The application does not store its domain object in the database directly. Instead, the domain objects are converted into document objects prior to persistance (and vice versa when reading). For example, a domain object:

```
public class User {
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PasswordSalt { get; private set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; private set; }

    public void ChangePassword(string oldPassword, string newPassword) {
        ...
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And the corresponing document object (which is what gets stored in the database):

```
class UserDocument {
    public static UserDocument FromEntity(User user) {
        ...
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    public User ToEntity() {
        ...
    }
}
```

So, if I want to change a user document stored in the database, I would typically load it, convert it into its corresponing domain object, make the changed (e.g call ChangePassword()), convert the domain object back into a document object and finally call IDocumentSession.Store() and SaveChanges(). This worked fine in RavenDB 1.

In RavenDB 2, however, it seems I am not allowed to call IDocumentSession.Save() with an entity that has the Id property set to a taken Id. When updating a document, the Id property will, by definition, already be taken.

The idea seems to be that in RavenDB 2 I would load an object, change it and then call SaveChanges() and the client would keep track of which objects that have been loaded and automatically send them to the server. Since I will make all changes in a proxy object (the domain object) and don't have the original document object left in memory, that is not possible for me.

Is it possible to configure RavenDB to use the behaviour present in RavenDB 1?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is NOT to have such separation between User and UserDocument. You want to be storing User objects into RavenDB using IDocumentSession - the fact they are being stored as documents is really an implementation details as far as you should be concerned.

There isn't any real difference between RavenDB 1 and 2 in this regard.

You should be able to do one of the two:

1. Load the object back using IDocumentSession.Load (or Query), change the Unit-of-Work directly and call SaveChanges when done
2. Load the object, change it to another obeject (using copy constructor or the like) and then store the new object under the same ID. You can do that by calling session.Store(obj, null, id).

Comment: Personally, I prefer to maintain a distinction between tha domain object and the "document object" as it allows me to, for example, make the domain object's PasswordHash-setter private, only making it possible to change its value through the method ChangePassword().

Comment: Something has changed between RavenDB 1 and 2; my pattern worked as is on RavenDB 1, but och 2 I get the error described above. There may be a way to call the session.Store(...) to make it wokd but I can't find it (that's why I'm asking here ;-) ). You suggestion unfortunately doesn't work since the second parameter to Store is a System.Guid; a non-nullable type. Maybe you could explain what it is you are trying to do with that line of code?

Comment: You can still have the setter private, all private properties are serialized. This distinction doesn't make sense and makes you go an extra mile for nothing. The call to Store as I suggested should work with Guid.Empty, and its idea is to force overriding the document under the specified ID with the new provided object.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't have the setter being private without leaking of the persistance layer into the domain layer. You may call me a purist but that's just how I roll (or what I want to try on this particular project, anyway) :-). Actually, using Guid.Empty doesn't work; the result is the same as if I just called Store(obj) - a NonUniqueObjectException is thrown. Thank you for trying to help, though.